# Creating Grouped Barplot with Three Independent Variables as Categories

Tags: r, bar-chart, visualization

I am very new to R and I would like to create a grouped bar plot. In my dataset, I have three independent variables (freedom, governan, polity). Every country has a value for each of these. I want these to be the groups on the x-axis of my graph. I also have the three variables freedomsubgroup, politysubgroup, governansubgroup. Every country is classified as low, middle, or high in all of these subgroups. I would like to split the groups in the graph in low, middle, and high, too. On the y-axis, I want the median value of each subgroup for another discrete variable (numenvIO).
My problem is that I am not sure that what I am trying to do is even possible. Can I make a grouped bar graph where the groups are three different independent variables?

My problem is that I am not sure that what I am trying to do is even possible. Can I make a grouped bar graph where the groups are three different independent variables?

All help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Camilla. Welcome to Stack Overflow. It sounds as though what you are trying to do will probably be possible in ggplot with the subgroups displayed via a combination of dodging, fill coloring and faceting. So the answer is a tentative 'yes'. Of course, this answer can only be general and qualitative, since your question is too. If you need more specific help, including code, then we would need a more specific question that includes data - you can [edit] your question to make it [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Good luck!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.